# Create Activity above tabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Like in topic - I want to create activity above tabHost that I already have.

I have button inside one of the tab and after click event I want to create activity that will overlay tabHost.

Another question is how to make it on application launch (It has to be hidden sometimes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
final (Button) yourButton = (Button)getViewById(R.id.your_button);  
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

YourActivity is the activity you wish start.

Comment: I've already tried very common code but got same result nullExcepction: `D/PhoneWindow(667): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44eb6020 has no id.
D/AndroidRuntime(667): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(667): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)` any idea?

Comment: Ok i've find out how to fixed it... I simply called wrong id from activity that I'am tried to display :). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

you try this code

```
public class Test_tedActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TabHost tabhost;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources();
       // TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent(this,Add.class);
        spec = tabhost.newTabSpec("Add")
                .setIndicator("add",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.plus)).setContent(intent);
        tabhost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent(this,Show.class);
        spec = tabhost.newTabSpec("Show")
                .setIndicator("Show",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.information)).setContent(intent);
        tabhost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent(this,Edit.class);
        spec = tabhost.newTabSpec("Edit")
                .setIndicator("Edit",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.edit)).setContent(intent);
        tabhost.addTab(spec);

        tabhost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }


}
```

xml this used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

mainfest this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ketan.test" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Test_tedActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Add" android:label="Add"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Edit" android:label="Edit"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Show" android:label="Show"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: That code I already have to present tabHost ... I want present another view with gonna be trigged from certain tab after onClick event.